# Can't create custom widget in tray menu with python pyside2

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

Not much info I've found, but looks like this snippet should works:

```py
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMenu, QPushButton, QSystemTrayIcon, QWidgetAction

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
menu = QMenu()
button = QPushButton("yoba")
action = QWidgetAction(menu)
action.setDefaultWidget(button)
menu.addAction(action)
menu.addAction("Quit").triggered.connect(sys.exit)
tray = QSystemTrayIcon()
tray.setContextMenu(menu)
tray.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But, I see only `Quit` item and empty item above, no push button appear. So, the question is "how to add custom widgets to tray menu?"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like this is a bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-26840

Since if call `menu.show()` instead of `tray.show()` everything is fine.